# How are long running tasks broken down without using threads?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios

If I have a long running task, how can that be broken down into a sequence of steps without having to resort to using a separate thread for its execution?

For example, suppose there is a spreadsheet application, and a re-calculation of a large numer of cells is to be performed, how can the model break it down into chunks? Is there a way of ios code posting events to itself for example, so it can do a chunk, post an event, do another chunk, post an event etc.

Or is the only way to use a separate thread?

I've got a stack of ios books that I've started to read, but I can't find a single mention of anything like this in any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use timers [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), but if anything takes a long time you'll be left with the UI hanging. Basically you need to make sure that all the work you do is < 0.01 seconds (approximately) each iteration, and delaying each iterations a little would make the UI more responsive.

The reason to use threads is to allow the OS to schedule things instead of you having to worry about it. If you run everything on the main thread (when you're trying to do a lot of work) you'll either freeze the UI or be constantly worrying about scheduling. If you use threads, the main thread has the proper priority so the UI remains responsive.

Comment: That's my point - some OSs (that I know of, Symbian and Brew) only have one thread, and you can run long running tasks within these but without making things unresponsive. This is great because you don't have to worry about deadlocks, race conditions, locking access to variables, and it makes stepping through code in an IDE a breeze. So I was wonding if a similar thing were possible with ios, but alas it seems thats not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading can be an option

---

You can always use the `delegation` (i think i just came up with that term, its using delegate and passing event to the object delegate whe something happens). Most of the iOS SDK objects use this, like `UITableView`, `NSURLConnection`, many many more.

Comment: I prefer not to use multiple threads whenever possible, is there no mechanism akin to Symbian's active objects, or Brew's post event etc. that allows one to achieve asynchronicity etc. without having to resort to multiple threads and all that that entails?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are asking is a way you design something, like a progress bar. At pre specified times throughout a long operation you update an Object, or the UI. This question is somewhat arbitrary, and i'm really not sure what your asking. Multithreading is a solution for long operations though.